# How to chain functions to a specific function

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I want to chain some function to a specific function which will only run when the preceding function executes successfully in python, and also the chained function should not be accessible elsewhere.

Example: I want a greeting function to run only when a name function runs successfully.

```
def name():
    name = str(input("please enter your name: "))
    while name not in (""," "):
        return name
    def greeting():
        message = "hello {}, welcome".format(name)
        print(message)
        return message
    def happy():
        mood = str(input("hello {},this is to check if you are happy, kindly answer 'yes' or 'no': ".format(name))
        if mood == "yes":
            reply = "that's good"
        else:
            reply = "oh dear, cheer up"
        print(reply)
    else:
        break

info = name()
print(info)
```

This code should run the greeting function and call the happy function only when the name function executes successfully and also neither the greeting or happy function should not be called without the name function.

But it does not execute as desired. It returns only the name.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unnecessary to define other functions within the `name()` function. I would suggest to define the functions separately, and then call them accordingly in a while loop below.

```
def name():
    name = str(input("please enter your name: "))
    if name not in (""," "):
        return name
    return None

def greeting(name):
    message = "hello {}, welcome".format(name)
    print(message)

def happy(name):
    mood = input("hello {},this is to check if you are happy, kindly answer 'yes' or 'no': ".format(name))
    if mood == "yes":
        reply = "that's good"
    else:
        reply = "oh dear, cheer up"
    print(reply)

while True:
    info = name()
    if info:
        greeting(info)
        happy(info)
        break
```

Edit: I realize you don't want the other functions to be accessible outside the scope of the name function. It can be done that way too (albeit rather strange).

```
def name():
    name_ = str(input("please enter your name: "))
    if name_ not in (""," "):
        def greeting(name):
            message = "hello {}, welcome".format(name)
            print(message)

        def happy(name):
            mood = input("hello {},this is to check if you are happy, kindly answer 'yes' or 'no': ".format(name))
            if mood == "yes":
                reply = "that's good"
            else:
                reply = "oh dear, cheer up"
            print(reply)
            return mood

        greeting(name_)
        return name_, happy(name_)

    return name()

info = name()
print(info)
```

Comment: Hello alec, thank you for your response. it really did the chaining I want but I actually want to return the the user input from name and happy function but it does not return from your code.

Comment: @SirBlaze I edited the return values, I think this is what you want now